# Equivalent to `code-line-numbers` for output in Quarto for revealjs slides

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, reveal.js, quarto

I am using Quarto to produce some revealjs slides using RStudio and have been using the `code-line-numbers` option to selectively highlight lines of code. For instance:

````
```{r, echo = TRUE}
#| code-line-numbers: "1|3"
x <- 1
y <- 2
x + y
x * y
```
````

Allows me to highlight the first and third lines of code in the presentation.

I would like to additionally be able to highlight certain lines in the *output*. For instance, if I wanted to only highlight the result of `x+y` but not `x*y`, is there a way of doing so? I wondered if there was an option for `output-line-number` or similar that might have the desired effect, but couldn't find anything like this.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible way to do this could be based on using [pandoc Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).

Here I have created a chunk-option `output-line-numbers` to specify which output lines to highlight (works just as `code-line-numbers` chunk option), but **please note that you must have to use `class-output: highlight` to get this line specific highlighting on chunk output.**

````
---
title: "Output Line highlight"
format: revealjs
filters:
  - output-line-highlight.lua
---

```{r, echo = TRUE}
#| code-line-numbers: "1"
#| class-output: highlight
#| output-line-numbers: "2"

for (i in 1:3) {
  print("This is some random line")
}
```
````

**output-line-highlight.lua**

```
function highlight(line_number)
  local highlighter = {
    CodeBlock = function(block)
      if block.classes:includes('highlight') then
        block.classes:insert('has-line-highlights')
        block.attributes["code-line-numbers"] = line_number
        return block
      end
  end
  }
  return highlighter
end


function Div(el)
  if FORMAT == 'revealjs' then
    if el.classes:includes('cell') then
      line_number = tostring(el.attributes["output-line-numbers"])
      return el:walk(highlight(line_number))
    end
  end
end
```

---

[image: output line highlighting for revealjs]

---

Comment: This is a great solution, any idea how it could be adapted to also work with Python output?

Comment: @FransRodenburg, I have not tested this with python output. Can you post a separate question with a small example quarto document?

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76338850/8770170), thanks!