# Python output highlighting in Quarto

Tags: python, r, lua, quarto, reveal.js

Continuing on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74981820/8770170) about code output highlighting in Quarto: Is it also possible to make this work with Python output?

A minimal working example:

````
---
title: "Output line highlighting"
format: revealjs
editor: visual
filters:
  - output-line-highlight.lua
---

## Regression Table 

In R:

```{r}
#| class-output: highlight
#| output-line-numbers: "9,10,11,12"
LM <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
summary(LM)
```

## Regression Table

In Python:

```{python}
#| class-output: highlight
#| output-line-numbers: "12,13,14,15,16,17"
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

iris = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('iris').data
LM = sm.OLS(iris['Sepal.Length'], sm.add_constant(iris['Sepal.Width'])).fit()
LM.summary2()
```
````

Rendering this file shows the Lua filter works for the R output, but not for Python.

Comment: The actual problem is that `class-output` chunk option is not supported in the case of `jupyter` engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python code chunk doesn't support the chunk option `output-class`. Instead, use the option `classes` and use the class `output-highlight`.
And for r-code chunk, you may use either `class-output: highlight` or `classes: output-highlight`.

And I have updated the filter to support the `classes: output-highlight` accordingly.

**output-line-highlight.lua**

```lua
function highlight(line_number)
  local highlighter = {
    CodeBlock = function(block)
      if block.classes:includes('highlight') then
        block.classes:insert('has-line-highlights')
        block.attributes["code-line-numbers"] = line_number
        return block
      end
  end
  }
  return highlighter
end

function add_highlight_class()
  return {
    CodeBlock = function(cb)
      if not cb.classes:includes('highlight') then
        cb.classes:insert('highlight')
      end
      return cb
    end
  }
end


function add_class_to_cb()
  return {
    Div = function(el)
      if el.classes:includes('cell-output') then
        return el:walk(add_highlight_class())
      end
    end
  }
end

function highlight_output_div()
  return {
    Div = function(div)
      if div.classes:includes('output-highlight') then
        return div:walk(add_class_to_cb())
      end
    end  
  }
end

function add_output_lnum()
  return {
    Div = function(el)
      if el.classes:includes('cell') then
        line_number = tostring(el.attributes["output-line-numbers"])
        return el:walk(highlight(line_number))
      end
    end
  }
end

function Pandoc(doc)
  if FORMAT == 'revealjs' then
    local doc = doc:walk(highlight_output_div())
    return doc:walk(add_output_lnum())
  end
end
```

**presentation.qmd**

````
---
title: "Output line highlighting"
format: revealjs
filters:
  - output-line-highlight.lua
---

## Regression Table 

In R:

```{r}
#| class-output: highlight
#| output-line-numbers: "9,10,11,12"
LM <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
summary(LM)
```

## Regression Table

In Python:

```{python}
#| classes: output-highlight
#| output-line-numbers: "2,4"

test = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in test:
  if i%2 == 0:
    print("this line is highlighted")
  else:
    print("this line is not highlighted")
```
````

---

[image: highlighted lines]

Comment: Thank you shafee, that fixes what I think is otherwise a real shortcoming of Quarto! This works perfectly.